# svchost.exe listening on port 5037, stops adb.exe from working

Tags: android, windows, adb

I've been troubleshooting this for hours and I'm so lost.

My Android Studio (Windows) has stopped being able to find devices, which I assumed was some kind of problem with `adb`. I navigated to the `platform-tools` folder and tried to run adb from there:

```
C:\Users\LeonardoPetrucci\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools>adb devices
adb.exe: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): No error
```

To fix this, I tried every solution I could find:

- Restarting
- Stopping adb.exe from task manager
- Reinstalling platform tools and Android Studio

None of this worked. So I went to check if there was something using port `5037` (the default Android Studio port):

```
C:\Users\LeonardoPetrucci\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools>netstat -aon|findstr "5037"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5037           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16420

C:\Users\LeonardoPetrucci\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools>tasklist|findstr "16420" 
svchost.exe                  16420 Services                   0     13,744 K
```

If I then go into Task Manager and stop process `16420` and try to run `adb` again:

```
C:\Users\LeonardoPetrucci\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools>adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
```

The problem here is that svchost.exe will randomly start up again and take over the port and if I restart, I need to do this whole process again.

Any idea why this would be happening?